# check for changes in md-select in angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to check for changes in the md-select, but I'm not able to achieve it with `$dirty`

```
     <div class="resourceForm" ng-form="resForm{{$index}}">
         <md-select name="resourceAllocForm" id="id{{resourceContent.activityId}}-{{x}}" ng-model="selRes[$parent.$index][x]" placeholder="Select Resource" class="md-no-underline" ng-keyup="resourceCheck($parent.$index)">
           <md-option ng-value="resource.id" ng-repeat="resource in resourceList track by resource.id">{{resource.roleProLabel}}</md-option>
        </md-select>
     </div>
```

and I have tried something like this

```
$timeout(function(parentIndex){
   $scope.resourceAllocForm['resForm' + parentIndex].$dirty;
   console.log('Form Edited');
}
```

Comment: You can use ng-change

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: Not sure why you pass `$parent.$index`, can you please create plunker/fiddle to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @PankajParkar - this has been resolved with `ng-change`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this,

```
<md-select ng-change="show(resource)" ng-model="selectedresource">
   <md-option ng-repeat="resource in resourceList track by resource.id" value="{{resource.id"}}">{{resource.roleProLabel}}
   </md-option>
<md-select>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.show = function(resource){
  console.log(show);
}
```